# How to FORCE_HTTPS on Cloud functions API endpoints

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I've configured a custom domain and certificate and hooked up the cloud functions api to my actions and this works fine.

Endpoints work over both https and http.

But I'd like to enforce https only.  Something like "FORCE_HTTPS: true" in the static buildpack. Is there someway that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should get an `X-Forwarded-Url` header in the action itself that you could inspect to force HTTPS. Using that in conjunction with secure actions via the web_key annotation should make it enforceable.

In the future, the API Gateway may be able to enforce this for you via the configuration specified in the Open API doc.